# How to migrate Sql Server to Oracle in different Computer

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008-r2, migrate

I want to migrate Sql Server from Computer A to Oracle in Computer B by LAN

I had migrate MySql to Oracle using sql developer in one machine..But now my case is in different computer..very confuse to configure the connection

Can u give me the best way?

thx!

Comment: Does your question boil down to "How do I use SQL Developer to connect to a database on a remote machine?"  It sounds like you are saying that you understand how to use the SQL Developer migration utility and that you are (or expect to be) satisfied with the output of that tool.

Comment: yeah..I can migrate using sql developer in one machine. But now I can not migrate database in different computer. Is there any trick using another tool to migrate it (different machine)??

Comment: Is the only problem you are having that you don't know how to connect to a database on a different machine via SQL Developer?  Why would you want to use a different tool rather than trying to debug your connectivity issue(s)?  Why would you expect the process of connecting to a remote database using that tool to be meaningfully different than the process of connecting to a remote database using SQL Developer?

Comment: do u have any suggest tool for this? cz I just know sql developer

Comment: I don't understand why you don't want to use SQL Developer if you're already familiar with that tool.  Does your question boil down to "How do I use SQL Developer to connect to a database on a remote machine?"

Comment: okay..I still using Sql Developer dude
my Question is, how i can using sql developer tool to migrate sql server to oracle db in Different Machines??

I already give the hostname my PC 2 IP address..but no result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer now..thankyou for help me to fix this
The solution is :
1. Change the localhost to the IP from listener.ora 
2. Turn off the firewall
3. From the sql developer, give the hostname ip address

and I can access it smoothly